# Can the YN-568EX be used as a commander for other 568EX flashes?

Tags: off-camera-flash, yongnuo, fill-flash

I see the 622 transceivers and 622 tx, but am I able to use a 568EX as an on camera fill flash and also control the 568EX that would be off camera?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No. The YN-568EX cannot act as an optical or radio master.** The YN-568EX**II** (Canon only at the time of this posting) can act as an optical TTL master, but has no radio transmitter capability built-in.

If you need TTL on-camera fill flash, your best bet, if you're a Canon shooter, would be to use a YN-622C on-camera, and to put the YN-568EX on its pass-through hotshoe, and use the camera menus to control the remote YN‑568EX via another YN-622C as a receiver on its hotshoe.

See also: the [TOYUG](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B77OmmGIg0gMVFpqNkpBYXBHajA/edit?pli=1).

If, however, you're a Nikon shooter, sandwiching a YN-622N will not be a great solution for you, because there is no control of remote flashes from the camera menu, and you'll have to use those, um, less-than-intuitive buttons and LEDs on the YN-622N to change the power setting on the remote flash. It will work, but it's a pain. Your best bet is probably to find a Nikon CLS commander speedlight of some kind, such as an SB-700, and put that on the passthrough shoe, and then you can control the remote lights via the SB-700's menus.

See also: [Flash Havoc's report on the YN-622N triggers](http://flashhavoc.com/yn-622n-nikon-ittl-trigger-full-details/) and [LightingRumors description of how to set remote power with a YN-622N](http://www.lightingrumours.com/yongnuo-yn-622n-review-part-2-high-speed-sync-remote-control-mode-4143#.VWfyS5SbHBs).

Comment: So you're saying use a 622 and a 568 on top of that on camera. Then, in the menu I'll be able to control the off camera?

Comment: @JoshBernthold Yup. The 622s have full TTL passthrough, and the camera menu can be used to control the remote flash via the 622. See [the TOYUG](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B77OmmGIg0gMVFpqNkpBYXBHajA/edit?pli=1) for more information on the 622s.

Comment: Now.... if I tell you I am a Nikon shooter that changes the answer doesnt it? Cant Canon only control in the menu or can Nikon as well?

Comment: @JoshBernthold Yes, it changes things as a Nikon shooter and the TOYUG becomes less useful. I'll update the answer for that.

Comment: One more thing, and then your opinion on something....  Is "sandwiching" having the trigger on the hot shoe and then the flash on the hot shoe trigger? Also, if I would go the sb-700 route for the commander, would you personally still go with the yn triggers or would you go something like the phottix strato ii triggers? I say this just because I was seeing that the mitros+ is the only way to be completely radio with nikon if I am correct? That is something I think I would like down the road like the canon 560ex-rt are.... (I should just flippin switch to canon lol)

Comment: @JoshBernthold Yes, "sandwiching" is putting the flash on top of the trigger on top of the camera. I don't think I can give you a knowledgeable opinion on which triggers to go for, since I'm a Canon shooter and have been very happy with my 622Cs, so I never looked much further (well, except at the YN600EX-RT. :D) But Phottix has a good reputation and seem to be being a system of compatible triggers, unlike Yongnuo.